# Ajax upload file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

In my PHP app I have some content generated by AJAX with form having file input.

This form is located in Bootstrap Modal. I write some data into inputs and upload file using jQuery File Upload Plugin 5.26 and it works fine.

I close modal and load the same content asynchronously by clicking on another list element.

I do the same as before and I have error: 4;

> No file was uploaded.

I used the same action, the same modal and form, only difference is that I render it twice using AJAX. Could anyone explain me how to fix this error and how to  upload second file?

I would like to add that data from text inputs has changed, but `$_FILES` is empty array.

Another info is that when I render view first I can upload file, close modal and upload second file.

Problem is when I render this view second time and try to upload file.

AJAX sending POST and getting view:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ksiazka/pobierz-partial",
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {             
                id: idObiektu,
                template: template,
                typ: typObiektu,
                fmodel: fmodel
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#ksiazka-tresc').html(data.html);
            }
        });
```

Rendering view:

```
public function pobierzPartialAction()
{       
   $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {            

        $id = $request->getPost('id');      
        $templatka = $request->getPost('template');      
        $typ = $request->getPost('typ');      
        $fmodel = $request->getPost('fmodel');      

        /* @var $wartosciDoTemplatki \Obiekty\Model\Ommost */
        $wartosciDoTemplatki = $this->pobierzWartosciDoTemplatki($templatka, $id, $typ, $fmodel);                     

        $htmlViewPart = new ViewModel();
        $htmlViewPart->setTerminal(true)
            ->setTemplate('template/' . $templatka)
            ->setVariables(array(
                'wartosci' => $wartosciDoTemplatki        
            ));

        $htmlOutput = $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('viewrenderer')
            ->render($htmlViewPart);


        $jsonObject = \Zend\Json\Json::encode(array(
            'html' => $htmlOutput
        ), true);
        echo $jsonObject;
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">              

<div class="col-sm-6" id="ksiazka-save-table-alert">
    <div class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert" style="padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 0; display: none">Pomyślnie zapisano</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
    <img src="/img/30-load.gif" alt="spinner" class="ksiazka-table-spinner" style="display: none">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">            
        <a class="btn btn-primary ksiazka-add-photo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dodaj rekord"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> 
        <a class="btn btn-danger karta-delete-row" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Usuń rekord"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>   
        <a class="btn btn-success karta-save-row" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Zapisz zmiany"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ksiazkaFileUpload"><div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Dodawanie zdjęcia</h4>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="min-height: 450px" id="hide-spinner">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form id="upload" method="post" action="/ksiazka/upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
                <input type="hidden" name="model" value="<?php echo $wartosci['model-pliki'] ?>" />                    
                <input type="hidden" name="tabela" value="<?php echo $wartosci['tabela-pliki'] ?>" />                    
                <input type="hidden" name="MASTER_ID" />    
                <?php if(isset($wartosci['OM_ID'])): ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="OM_ID" value="<?php echo $wartosci['OM_ID'] ?>" />       
                <?php endif ?>

                <label for="NR">NR</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NR" />   
                <label for="OPIS">Opis</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OPIS" />                     
                <div id="drop" style="margin-top: 10px">
                    <input type="file"  name="upl"  />         
                    <a href="#" class="file btn btn-primary pull-right disabled"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Dodaj</a>

                </div>                   
                <ul style="margin-top: 20px">
                         The file uploads will be shown here 
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Upload file action:

```
public function uploadFileAction()
{       
    $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip', 'txt', 'rtf');       

    var_dump($_FILES, $_POST);

    if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0)
    { 

        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
            echo '{"status":"error"}';
            exit;
        }            

        $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name']);             

        $idTypu = 2;

        $values = $_POST;

        $model = $values['model'];
        $tabela = $values['tabela'];              

        $values['ID_TYPU_PLIKU'] = $idTypu;

        $values['PLIK'] = 'empty_blob()';
        $values['OPIS'] = "'". $values['OPIS'] . "'";
        $values['NR'] = "'". $values['NR'] . "'";

        $values['NAZWA_PLIKU'] = "'". $_FILES['upl']['name'] . "'";

        unset( $values['model']);
        unset( $values['tabela']);

        $session = new \Zend\Session\Container('namespace');
        $zasobId = $session->item;     

        $zasob = $this->getZasobyTable()->zwrocSchematPoId($zasobId);

        $fun  = 'get' . $model . 'Table';           

        $this->$fun()->saveUploadedFile($file, $values, $tabela, $zasob);
        echo 'ok';
        exit;
    }

    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}
```

JS script:

```
var ul = $('#upload ul');

$('.file').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Simulate a click on the file input button
    // to show the file browser dialog

    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
});

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
$('#upload').fileupload({

    // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
    dropZone: $('#drop'),
    pasteZone: $(document),
    // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
    // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
    add: function (e, data) {

        var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="20" data-height="20"'+
            ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

        // Append the file name and file size
        tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                     .append('<b>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</b>');

        // Add the HTML to the UL element
        data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

        // Initialize the knob plugin
        tpl.find('input').knob();

        // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
        tpl.find('span').click(function(){

            if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }

            tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                tpl.remove();
            });

        });

        // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
        var jqXHR = data.submit();
    },

    progress: function(e, data){

        // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

        // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
        // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
        data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

        if(progress == 100){
            data.context.removeClass('working');
        }
    },

    fail:function(e, data){ 
        // Something has gone wrong!
        data.context.addClass('error');
    },

    done: function (e, data) {
    }

});
```

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code snippets, this question does not contain enough information for anyone to answer objectively.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The least you can say is that they heard you O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any code yet but the most common mistake in `ajax` transfers are how they define the `data` in the call. I upload files like this: *(try it)*

```
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
          //show a success message or something else
        }
      });
```